# Improving upon a feature on a Wordpress site that changes phone number displayed to user in the header based on their IP address

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

My question is regarding suggestions for improvements of a feature I created on a Wordpress site that changes the phone number displayed to user in the header based on their IP address. The default is a 1-866 number to be displayed if area does not appear to be serviced etc.

[image]

In my `functions.php` file I created the below functions to use [ipinfo.io](https://ipinfo.io) to find the city of the user, compare it to the field of city I created to be associated with each location post and then if there is a match the second function returns the phone number field associated with that location. See functions below:

```
//Returns users city based on IP address
function get_the_user_ip() {
    if ( ! empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] ) ) {
    //Checks if IP is from shared internet
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif ( ! empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] ) ) {
    //Checks if IP is passed from proxy
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } 
    else {
    //Most trustworthy source of IP address
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    //$ip='104.238.96.194'; //--used this to test different IP addresses--

    //Uses ipinfo.io to find location information based on IP address
    $details = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://ipinfo.io/{$ip}"));
    //Returns city value from the details array
    $city=$details->city;
    return apply_filters('wpb_get_ip', $city );
    }

//Returns correct phone number based on a user's location
function zip_display(){

    $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_type'         => 'Locations',
    'post_status' => ('publish')

    );

$wp_query = new WP_Query($args); 
//var_dump($wp_query);
if( $wp_query->have_posts() ): while( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
        $userCity=get_the_user_ip();
        $stateField=get_field('state');
        $cityField=get_field('city');                
        $phoneField=get_field('phone_number');

        if($userCity==$cityField){
             return ( '<span class="phone-span">' . $phoneField . '</span>');
         }      
       endwhile; 
       wp_reset_postdata(); 
endif;
}
```

To display the correct phone number in the header I inserted a `<div>` element with the `id` of phone directly into an auxiliary header like so:

[image]

Then to target this div id I inserted the below JavaScript directly into my `footer.php`

```
<script>document.getElementById("phone").innerHTML = '<?php echo zip_display(); ?>';</script>
```

Is this an acceptable way to go about doing this? Everything is working correctly more or less right now. The only issue I am having so far is it seems for at least one person neither the default 1-866 number is being displayed to them nor a specific number based on their location? Does anyone have any ideas why that would be? Does it possibly have to do with a browser setting that does not allow JavaScript scripts to be shown in the way I constructed it?

Answer (score 0):

The `zip_display()` function in your posted code will only return a `span` element if the `$userCity` matches the `$cityField`. You need to return the span containing the default phone number if the cities do not match. Change your condition to something like this:

```
if($userCity==$cityField){
    return ( '<span class="phone-span">' . $phoneField . '</span>');
}else{
    return ( '<span class="phone-span">' . $defaultPhoneNumber . '</span>');
}
```

Comment: Would that not be taken care of by the `<div id="phone"><span class="phone-span">1-866-000-0000</span></div>` I entered on the header?

Comment: Also that would not would not be ideal because I am looping through location posts in my function. Therefore, I believe multiple page refreshes would be needed for a user to see the correct number.

Answer (score 0):

In order to improve the functionality of this feature I did the following:

1. In my `get_the_user_ip` function I decided to use the free WordPress plugin [GeoIP Detection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/geoip-detect/), instead of [ipinfo.io](https://ipinfo.io/)

See modification to `get_the_user_ip` function below:

```
`//Returns users city based on IP address`
function get_the_user_ip() {
    if ( ! empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] ) ) {
    //Checks if IP is from shared internet
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif ( ! empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] ) ) {
    //Checks if IP is passed from proxy
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } 
    else {
    //Most trustworthy source of IP address
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    $record = geoip_detect2_get_info_from_ip($ip, NULL);
    $city=$record->city->name;
    return apply_filters('wpb_get_ip', $city );
    }
```

2. In my `zip_display` function I added a return statement outside of while loop. In order to return a default phone number if the user's city cannot be matched to a location. This works better than an if/else statement because it will only execute once the loop has completed all iterations.

   ```
   function zip_display(){

       $args = array(
       'posts_per_page'    => -1,
       'post_type'         => 'Locations',
       'post_status' => ('publish')

       );

   $wp_query = new WP_Query($args); 

   if( $wp_query->have_posts() ): while( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
           $userCity=get_the_user_ip();

           $cityField=get_field('city');                
           $phoneField=get_field('phone_number');      
           if($userCity==$cityField){
                return ('<a class="phone-span" href="tel:1-'. $phoneField . '">' . $phoneField . '</a>');
            }  
          endwhile; 
                return('<a class="phone-span" href="tel:1-866-000-0000">1-866-000-0000</a>');
          wp_reset_postdata(); 
   endif;
   }
   ```
3. Lastly I modified my `footer.php` file, separating my JavaScript script into a variable so that the script would not throw an `Uncaught TypeErron: Cannot read property '....' of null`.

   `<script>
       var ipphone = '<?php echo zip_display(); ?>'
       if(ipphone){document.getElementById("phone").innerHTML = ipphone;}
   </script>`